# Password encryption in Sonar

Tags: encryption, sonarqube, salt

I'm using Yale's CAS to integrate my sonar system and I have problems validating my login username and password, Since I have known that sonar uses crypted_password and salt to store original password, but I can't figure out how sonar generates crypted_password with original password and the random salt. What I need are the encryption algorithm and encryption srategy.

Any of your reply will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All the encryption-related classes are located in the sonar-plugin-api module. See https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar/tree/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/config

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, I'm viewing the sorcecodes, wish to have a good luck and best wishes to you!(Tyler Liu from China)